# Page transition using next.js and R3F

Tags: next.js, three.js, webgl, transition, react-three-fiber

I'm trying to make a transition between two pages like on this site. https://www.alcre.co.kr

I create my site with next.js, as in the example site. Normally, Ajax and three.js are used in WordPress themes and you can move to the next page without refreshing the page.

However, things are a little different in next.js. Both pages contain statically literal HTML. Can such a transition be made?